# Not able to achieve desired speed up using openmp

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I am trying to use openmp directive to parallelize a piece of code but not being able to achieve any speed up. Folowing is the piece of code that I am trying to parllelize:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i,j) shared(a,x,n) default(none)
{
  for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
  {
    x[j] = A(j,n,n)/A(j,j,n);
   #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
    for (i=0;i<=j-1;i++)
    {
      A(i,n,n )= A(i,n,n) - A(i,j,n)*x[j];
    }
 }
}
```

The value of n is 1000. The A(i,n,n) is defined macro which is used to access to array a. 
As I increase the number of threads the execution time increases or it remains the same. The machine I am working on has 4 cores. I am suprised that that there is no speed up even when the number of threads is 2.
I am not able to figure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you time your code? Is that CPU time or wallclock time?

Comment: "shared(a,x,n)" --> where is `a`. I guess in `A`. How is `A` defined?

Comment: You should be aware that thread creation consumes some time, too! There needs a stack to be allocated for and initialised, the thread itself must be managed by the OS (scheduling, ...), and afterwards, the thread must be cleaned up again. Possibly your speed gain in parallelising the loop is consumed up by the thread management overhead (so your problem might simply be too small to profit from parallelism...).

Comment: Assuming the issue isn't about timing, one obvious issue you might be facing is false sharing of your array `a`. This would be due to your `dynamic` scheduling as 2 threads would likely manage contiguous `i` indexes, while updating `a[n][n][i]` (depending on the definition of macro `A`). So 1/ show the macro and 2/ try something like `dynamic(4)` for your scheduling.

Comment: The code is rather bogus. Writing to `x[j]` is done by all threads in parallel non-atomically, so it's a race condition and can be wrong even though they all compute the same value.

Comment: In passing *Not able to achieve desired speed up using openmp* isn't a question, it's the usual state of affairs in parallel programming.

Comment: Have you verified that multiple threads are being used? What compile options are you using. What is your hardware, compiler, and OS?

Comment: How do you time your code?

Answer (score 0):

Since `n>>#CPUs` (I don't think you have 1000 CPUs), it is not wise to parallelize the inner loop. In your example, you redistribute the work at each iteration.
Instead, it is wiser to parallelize the outer loop. This way, the value of `x[j]` won't be updated concurrently by different threads (as [Zulan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620382/zulan) mentioned), and you will have much less work re-distribution.
In that case, using *dynamic* scheduling is wise since the quantity of work change at each iteration.

- Note: You will have to change the order of the calculation, the current implementation does not allow you to move the parallelization to the outer loop since all of the threads will update the same value (`A[i][n][n]`).

Although it is true that threads creating take time, the threads are not recreated at each iteration. They are only created once on the top `#pargma` statement and running concurrently for the entire following clause.